# Next.js 13 beta app directory with nested layout not scrolling to top on route change using next/link

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Demo over [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/ali-issa/scroll-test/main). You need to scroll down and then click on a link in the header.

I have a `layout.tsx` file in the `src` directory and another `layout.tsx` file in the `(public)` directory that includes a sticky `<Header />` component. The expected behavior is that the page scrolls to the top on route change using a `<Link>`.

What actually happens is that the page scrolls to top minus the `Header` height. I've tried to include `scrollRestoration: true` in `next.config.js` with no luck. The issue is also present in the latest canary release.

Another thing that keeps happening is that I'm getting a `Hydration error` when refreshing the page multiple times. I'm not sure if the two issues are related.

I would like to know if my layout structure is invalid or if I'm using the the new layout feature incorrectly before opening an issue on GitHub.

Would appreciate it if someone can help figure out what's going on because it has been driving me crazy.

```
├──(public)
│   ├── page.tsx
│   └── layout.tsx
└── layout.tsx (root layout)
```

```
// src/layout.tsx

import "assets/styles/globals.css";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html>
      <head />
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

```
// src/(public)/header.tsx

import Link from "next/link";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-200 h-12 sticky top-0 z-50">
      <div className="flex flex-row mx-auto max-w-7xl h-full space-x-4 items-center ">
        <Link href="/">Home</Link>
        <Link href="/about">About</Link>
        <Link href="/contact">Contact</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

```
// src/(public)/layout.tsx

import Header from "./header";

export default function PublicLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <main className="py-16">{children}</main>
    </>
  );
}

// I've tried <main className="py-16"><Header />{children}</main> but the issue persisted
```

Comment: Hey @Hofmann, ever figured out how to solve this?

Comment: Hi @AndreVitorio, I haven't found a solution yet. I'm living with it for now, and moved on to something else. I guess it's time to open an issue on GitHub. Please let me know if you ever find a fix and I will do the same. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution for this, we need to add

```
useEffect(() => { // ️ scroll to top on page load
  window.scrollTo({top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
}, []);
```

on `layout.tsx` so that on every rerender by route this will be called

thanks

Answer (score -1):

I checked with newest version of next and this issue is fixed.

Update next package from 13.1.1 to 13.4.3.

```
"next": "13.4.3",
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

in  your layout  page  try  to do that

```
 useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top:0,
      left:0,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    })
  }, [])
```